# Please write this loop and try/except in one line with python

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, except

How can I condense this code into a single line? Thanks for the help.

```
for query in announcements:
    try:
        query.price = int(query.price)
        listme.append(query.price)
    except:
        print(listme)
```

Comment: Do you have a shortage of newline characters in your environment?

Comment: @Derlin Surprisingly, it can be done. See Ofer Sadan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will basically do the same thing, without the printing of failure:

```
listme.extend(int(query.price) for query in announcements if query.price.isdigit())
```

This assumes that `query.price` is a string and that `listme` is an existing list.

Trying to print the failures as well would be tricky (and unreadable) but possible:

```
listme.extend(x for x in [int(query.price) if query.price.isdigit() else print(query.price) for query in announcements] if x is not None)
```

Unless this is a homework assignment or something, it's generally very bad practice to insist that your code fits in one messy unreadable line, so don't do it

Comment: `parse_float = lambda x, y=exec("def f(s):\n try:\n  return float(s)\n except:  return None"): f(x)`

Comment: If `query.price` is float within string literals, it fails.

Comment: @SayandipDutta the code in the question would fail as well. This is equivalent